# No bean could be found in the registry for: endpointMapping of type: org.apache.camel.component.spring.ws.bean.CamelSpringWSEndpointMapping

Tags: apache-camel, spring-ws

I have recently started working on a project in which we have expose SOAP end point using Apache camel with spring Ws and few endpoints for ActiveMQ as well. Version which i am using are as below :

Spring boot : 1.5.3
camel-spring-ws : 2.17.1

I have done all the configuration and created as explained in the Apache camel Spring WS page. Different configuration files and pom files are as below .

But whenever i am deploying my app i am getting below . Could not find any relevant answer for this. Please help.

Exception :

```
    Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: spring-ws://rootqname:%7Bhttp://springWsSecurity.com/types/helloworld%7DSayHelloInput?endpointMapping=%23endpointMapping due to: No bean could be found in the registry for: endpointMapping of type: org.apache.camel.component.spring.ws.bean.CamelSpringWSEndpointMapping
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:678) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:80) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:219) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:112) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:118) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.model.FromDefinition.resolveEndpoint(FromDefinition.java:69) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.getEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:94) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1278) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:204) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry for: endpointMapping of type: org.apache.camel.component.spring.ws.bean.CamelSpringWSEndpointMapping
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.mandatoryLookup(CamelContextHelper.java:173) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.util.EndpointHelper.resolveReferenceParameter(EndpointHelper.java:326) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.util.EndpointHelper.resolveReferenceParameter(EndpointHelper.java:308) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.resolveAndRemoveReferenceParameter(DefaultComponent.java:415) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.spring.ws.SpringWebserviceComponent.addEndpointMappingToConfiguration(SpringWebserviceComponent.java:140) ~[camel-spring-ws-2.17.1.jar:2.17.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.spring.ws.SpringWebserviceComponent.addConsumerConfiguration(SpringWebserviceComponent.java:83) ~[camel-spring-ws-2.17.1.jar:2.17.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.spring.ws.SpringWebserviceComponent.createEndpoint(SpringWebserviceComponent.java:67) ~[camel-spring-ws-2.17.1.jar:2.17.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:116) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:631) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
```

Pom.xml as below :

```
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project`enter code here`.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <amq.version>5.4.2</amq.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
            <version>${amq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
            <version>${amq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-ws</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

WebServiceConfig.java as below

```
package com.ordermanagement.apache.camel.OrderManagementUsingApacheCamel.configuration;

import org.apache.camel.Endpoint;
import org.apache.camel.component.spring.ws.bean.CamelEndpointMapping;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.ws.server.EndpointAdapter;
import org.springframework.ws.server.EndpointInterceptor;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.MessageEndpointAdapter;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.SimpleWsdl11Definition;


@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ishantg/ws");
    }

    @Bean(name="helloworld")
    public SimpleWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(){
        SimpleWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
        defaultWsdl11Definition.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource("wsdl/greeting.wsdl"));
        return defaultWsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public PayloadLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor(){
        return new PayloadLoggingInterceptor();
    }

    @Bean
    public EndpointAdapter endpoint(){
       return new MessageEndpointAdapter();
    }


    @Bean(name = "camelEndpointMapping")
    public CamelEndpointMapping camelEndpointMapping(PayloadLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor ) {
        CamelEndpointMapping endpointMapping = new CamelEndpointMapping();
        endpointMapping.setInterceptors(new EndpointInterceptor[]{loggingInterceptor});
        return endpointMapping;
    }

}
```

SpringWs Route as below :

```
package com.ordermanagement.apache.camel.OrderManagementUsingApacheCamel.route;


import org.apache.camel.LoggingLevel;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


@Configuration
public class SpringWsRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringWsRoute.class);

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("spring-ws:rootqname:{http://springWsSecurity.com/types/helloworld}SayHelloInput?endpointMapping=#endpointMapping")
               .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Spring ws Recieved Message");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bean is named

```
 @Bean(name = "camelEndpointMapping")
```

But in the Camel endpoint you do not use the same name

```
 endpointMapping=#endpointMapping
```

Change either of them so they use the same name, such as

```
 endpointMapping=#camelEndpointMapping
```